# Is there a way to add additional code metrics in SonarQube without having to write my own plugin?

Tags: java, sonarqube, metrics

I want to start tracking code metrics over time in my team's codebase. We decided that the five metrics we were primarily going to be concerned with is Coupling Between Object, Halstead Effort, Lack of Cohesion of Methods, Weighted Method Complexity, and Response for Class. There are plenty of tools for just one time measuring these metrics over our code, but I want to track it. A coworker mentioned Sonar (now apparently called SonarQube).

I got an instance set up and it looks like it has the timeline support I need, but it lacks any good code metrics beyond code complexity and code coverage. Plenty of search results tell me things like how Lack of Cohesion of Methods actually used to be in it but were deprecated and removed. I need these metrics, regardless of if they are officially supported or through a community plugin, but I haven't found a non-deprecated one that adds them.

Manual metrics exist, but we have hundreds of classes and I don't want to have to make a manual measurement for each class every week. It would become a full time job. I'd rather avoid having to write my own plugin. If I went that route, I might as well just write a cron job that runs once a week to pull the latest, get the analysis I need with a local tool (currently using MetricsReloaded), and dump the local analysis into a local database where I can do whatever with it later. These approaches seem poor and a better one has to exist, right?

How can I get these metrics to be tracked by SonarQube?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to import the result of a tool in SonarQube to track certain metrics over time.

The best course of action in my opinion would be to write a plugin not to compute the metrics but to import the report generated by your tool. That is probably the best reusable option and you don't have to reinvent the wheel and benefit from SonarQube features.
This is how the coverage plugins are usually written (for java). You can have a look at Cobertura or Clover plugin or even Generic Coverage plugin to see how at SonarSource we write those kind of plugins.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are not using the right tool for your use case. Sonar is just not meant to work incrementally. [Teamscale](http://teamscale.com) is exactly what you are looking for. It is an incremental analysis tool that tracks metrics and quality deficits over time.
You can either

- choose from the wide variety of **built-in metrics** and analysis
- implement your own **Custom Checks** for Teamscale or
- automatically **upload metrics and findings** from external tools. Teamscale will also track these over time just like any other finding.

I think the third option is what you need for your use case.

*Just a side note: You might want to rethink your choice of metrics if you really want to improve the quality of your code. You should read the following [blog post](https://www.cqse.eu/en/blog/mccabe-cyclomatic-complexity/) which explains why McCabe is a poor choice. The same arguments hold for the metrics you mentioned.*

Comment: I thought Sonar stores only snapshots of the past without the possibility to later inspect the code changes that caused metric changes. But maybe we have a different notion of incremental here.

Answer (score -1):

Let's try [SourceMeter](https://www.sourcemeter.com/) - a source code analyzer tool. 
It has a lot of source code metrics.
There is also a plug-in for SonarQube.

Comment: Whilst this answer is useful, SO requires some more information than just a link. as an answer.